# .Net Download Webcontent

Tags: javascript, html, .net

I'm trying to get the HTML-Content like it is displayed in Chrome "Developer Console".
So I've already tried to download the content via the Webclient Class, but missing some tags and result is another one than in Chrome. I guess the cause of this is the not-execution of javascript or something else.
I tried also the WebBrowser Control, but same result.

So how could I get this content?

I've thought about to using something like a Firefox-Plugin in my application, but I'm not sure, whether it's possible to control this Plugin via code and to get the content.

Currently, I'm trying it in a Winform Application, but it is also possible for me to jump to Asp.Net or WPF.

Any suggestions on this issue?

THANX

Comment: The WebBrowser control should be able to do it, have you tried adding a WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler?

Comment: Yeah, the page is fully loaded, but looks very different to that one in Chrome for example. Also the source of this is another one. Currently, I have wrote a Chrome extension for getting the same data, but I still like to find a solution in .Net